# Trying to get the user's location loaded onto a map, using a singleton, service and an alarm

Tags: java, android, service, singleton, alarmmanager

So far I have an alarm set to wake up every so often and then take the latitude and longitude of the user. This is stored in the singleton class `Position` which will be loaded in a different activity and placed as a marker on a map, based on the last recorded position.

**Objective**
I want the app to track the user's location even when it is closed, as to why i've used an `AlarmManager` to wake the device after a certain amount of seconds and take the coordinates, until they request to stop it.

**Problem**
Even though the class returns the previously-recorded `Position` values i.e. the coordinates, the activity which calls this to place the position on the map returns the coordinates (0.0, 0.0) i.e. null, assuming that it is initialising the object as if it doesn't already exist.

What could be the problem?

**Position - the Singleton**

```
public class Position {

    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private String coordinate;
    private String service;
    private static Position instance;

    private Position() {

    }

    public String getCoordinate() {
        return coordinate;
    }

    public void setCoordinate(String coordinate) {
        this.coordinate = coordinate;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public String getService() {
        return service;
    }

    public void setService(String service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public static Position getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Position();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

**The Alarm - where the location is tracked**

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
        wl.acquire();

        // get the service code
        String serviceCode = intent.getStringExtra("serviceCode");

        // get the last known location
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        //store the latitude and longitude locally
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        String coordinate = latitude + ", " + longitude;

        Position pos = Position.getInstance();
        Log.d("", "Previous position: " + pos.getCoordinate());

        pos.setLatitude(latitude);
        pos.setLongitude(longitude);
        pos.setCoordinate(coordinate);The 
        pos.setService(serviceCode);

        Log.d("", "Found new position: " + pos.getCoordinate());

        wl.release();
    }

    public void SetAlarm(Context context) {
        AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 10000, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
    }

    public void CancelAlarm(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(sender);
    }
}
```

**Location Service - what initialises the alarm**

```
public class LocationService extends android.app.Service {

    Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
    private NotificationManager nm;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        showNotification();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        alarm.SetAlarm(LocationService.this);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

   private void showNotification() {
        // set up notification label to notify user that the app is still tracking the location
        nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        CharSequence text = "Press to stop tracking";

        // don't let user close it, for the purpose of always letting them know the location tracker is still running
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.fav_buses, text, System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

        // for older APIs
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, PushLocationActivity.class), 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Tracking Your Location", text, contentIntent);

        nm.notify(R.string.notification_id, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        alarm.CancelAlarm(LocationService.this);
        nm.cancel(R.string.notification_id);
        Log.d("", "DESTROYED");
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**StopsFragment - where the NullPointerException occurs**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    stops = new HashMap<>();
    stopList = StopList.getInstance(getActivity()).getStops();

    request = getArguments().getString("request");

    position = Position.getInstance();
    Log.d("", position.getCoordinate());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not follow that approach, this will drain the device battery. Android have specific API to receive significant location changes for a user, you should use them. Follow this links: 
https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

Just adapt the code, instead of an activity, the code should be executed from a service, and the service should be called to execute on boot.

Comment: I used this previously, but the objective is for the app to get location updates even when it is closed, as to why I am using an `AlarmManager`.

Comment: With that code your application will be notified when the user changes the location, even if the app is closed. See this code: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdates

Just change the code from an activity to a service and start the service on boot.